# Unable to fetch json in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am not sure why I am not able to fetch the json page test.php. The code should work fine and fetch the JSON page as card view. It shows Loading and then just a blank page.

I have a ListItem java file too which I have not posted below. It just contains a initializing constructor and three get String methods.
There is no error but the logcat shows the following two lines in red while the blank page loads

Error

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

ListItem java file

```
public class ListItem {
    private String head;
    private String description;
    private String imageURL;

    public ListItem(String head, String description, String imageURL) {
        this.head = head;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageURL=imageURL;
    }

    public String getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

MAIN JAVA FILE

```
public class news extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String URL_DATA="https://10.2.0.175/test.php";

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recylerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        listItems=new ArrayList<>();
        loadRecyclerViewData();
    }
    public void loadRecyclerViewData(){
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading data..");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_DATA, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("heroes");
                    for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject o=array.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem item =new ListItem(
                                o.getString("name"),
                                o.getString("about"),
                                o.getString("image")

                        );
                        listItems.add(item);
                    }
                    adapter=new myadapter(listItems,getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

MY ADAPTER JAVA FILE

```
public class myadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ListItem> listItems;
    private Context context;

    public myadapter(List<ListItem>s, Context context) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem listItem=listItems.get(position);
        holder.Heading.setText(listItem.getHead());
        holder.Heading.setText(listItem.getDescription());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView Heading;
        public TextView Description;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Heading=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            Heading=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        }
    }
}
```

MAIN XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="club.pithynews.pithy_iitbhilaiapp.news">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

LIST ITEM XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/cardview_compat_inset_shadow">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HEADING"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your cardView in main XML should be recyclerView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recylerview"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

try this code.

Comment: this error is because you are trying to put your recycler view object into a CardView. make it RecyclerVIew and everything should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. But I am not able to fetch the JSON page even after it shows the progress dialog 'Loading'. It is just blank.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: in your adapter constructor put this line this.listItems=s; instead of this.listItems=listItems

Comment: post stacktrace.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: i mean edit your question and update whole stacktrace there.

Comment: Done. Please check it out

Comment: post your whole logcat buddy. with this I cant find at which line your app is crashing.

Comment: App is not crashing. It is just not displaying the json content and there is no error/crash. Just two lines in red which I shared with you

Comment: change this line in your main private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter; with private myadapter adapter.

Comment: the error can be ignored. but the data is loading in recyclerview or not?

Comment: No. It is not loading any data. It is blank

Comment: post your model class(ListItem).

Answer (score 0):

Check your **MAIN XML FILE**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recylerview"></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Update it to:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recylerview" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. But I am not able to fetch the JSON page even after it shows the progress dialog 'Loading'. It is just blank.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"></android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It should be

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. But I am not able to fetch the JSON page even after it shows the progress dialog 'Loading'. It is just blank.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Comment: @SuryaTeja Post it as a new question, as the question you asked here has given you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your xml file-:

For Recycler view-:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recylerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
               />
```

For Card View-:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recylerview"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue. But I am not able to fetch the JSON page even after it shows the progress dialog 'Loading'. It is just blank.

Comment: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null